# Need to disable JQuery Table navigation when focus in on an input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to disable [table navigation](http://projects.arkanis-development.de/table_navigation/) when the focus is on an input field.
I could bind to the keypress/keydown events and do it.
Does table navigation support something for this? Any other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the documentation it appears that you could doing something like:

```
$(":input.myField")
  .focus(function(){
    $.tableNavigation({disabled:true});
  })
  .blur(function(){
    $.tableNavigation({disabled:false});
  });
```

This assumption is based off of the following statement in the documentation:

> *To update the used options just call jQuery.tableNavigation again with the new options.*